# display Woocommerce subscription actions to any of custom page or dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using WooCommerce subscriptions and am trying to create a custom flow in the dhasboard for the user.

Currently user logs in > dashboard shows, I have custom code to show if subscription status is "active" or "on-hold". If it is on hold, the user currently has to click on view subscription, then click on a listed subscription and then click renew in the actions section.

I want to move this actions button to renew an "on-hold" subscription out of the subscription-details.php file and into the dashboard.php file to reduce these steps.

Here is the snippet i've found that I think relates to the renew action button:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_before_actions', $subscription ); ?>
    <?php $actions = wcs_get_all_user_actions_for_subscription( $subscription, get_current_user_id() ); ?>
    <?php if ( ! empty( $actions ) ) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php esc_html_e( 'Actions', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $action['url'] ); ?>" class="button <?php echo sanitize_html_class( $key ) ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $action['name'] ); ?></a>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_after_actions', $subscription ); ?>
```

I tried to bring this into the dashboard.php file, however I get an error saying the site is experiencing technical difficulties.

Any ideas on how I could bring this renewal action button into the dashboard.php file instead?

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show any of action in your custom page or dashboard then use below code and set action according to your requirements

```
function addCancelButton($subscription) {
    $actions = wcs_get_all_user_actions_for_subscription( $subscription, get_current_user_id() );
    if(!empty($actions)){
        foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ){
            if(strtolower($action['name']) == "cancel"){
                $cancelLink = esc_url( $action['url'] );
                echo "<a href='$cancelLink' class='button cancel'>".$action['name']."</a>";
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_subscriptions_actions', 'addCancelButton', 10 );
```

If you want to edit My account page then i suggest to use this hook in your child theme

```
woocommerce_account_dashboard
```

Here is code for same

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard','add_account_content_kiki' );


function add_account_content_kiki() {

  if( has_active_subscription() ){ // Current user has an active subscription 

        echo '<div class="woocommerce-message woocommerce-message--info woocommerce-Message woocommerce-Message--info woocommerce-info"><a class="woocommerce-Button button" href="www.google.com">Test Now</a>Test link - shop now</div>';

    // Example of displaying something
        echo 'You have active subscription';
}

}
```

you have to add this function also in function file

```
function has_active_subscription( $user_id='' ) {
    // When a $user_id is not specified, get the current user Id
    if( '' == $user_id && is_user_logged_in() ) 
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    // User not logged in we return false
    if( $user_id == 0 ) 
        return false;

    return wcs_user_has_subscription( $user_id, '', 'active' );
}
```

Reference of hook - https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

All hook you can use from here for woo commerce my account page  - https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-account-pages/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, I appreciate it however I already know how to edit the my account page... I am wanting to add the 'renew' subscription button from the subscription-details.php page which I think is the snippet provided, to the my-account dashboard.php page.

Comment: @Kiki check updated answer, i have added hook to show cancel button same you can do for any of your custom action

Comment: @JitendraPopat, you mentioned "set action according to your requirements". In that case how I get $subscription variable? Have you achieved listing all subscription on custom page?

Comment: @Gangesh yes i achieved listing of all subscription also plan of user with details of subscription